# Positive sentence after but

Tags: conjunctions

> I don't like reading, **but I like cooking.**
>
> I like cooking, **but I don't like reading.**

Can I use a positive sentence after "but"?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can.  *But* indicates something that contrasts with the first part of the sentence, or is unexpected after the first part of the sentence.  That can be either a positive or negative clause, just like you used.

References:
 - [Conjunctions](http://grammar.ccc.commnet.edu/grammar/conjunctions.htm)
 - [But](http://www.perfectyourenglish.com/usage/but.htm)

Comment: So the sentence "I don't like reading, but I like cooking." is perfectly correct?

Comment: @user44430 - Yes, it's fine.

Comment: Yes, because  the first part of the sentence is in contrast to the second part.

Comment: @user44430 The contrast can also be between _good_ and _better:_ "I like cooking, but I prefer reading."

Answer (score 1):

Incidentally, you can also use a "but + positive clause" form after a positive clause if the second positive is comparatively greater or stronger than the first positive clause. Note that "positive" and "negative" in these cases refer to the clauses confirming or denying some statement, and not their "value".

> Ex.1  I like cooking, but I like reading even more.
>
> Ex.2  There were a lot of smart people, but the stupid people outnumbered them.